# How do I make second disk in zpool bootable?

Tags: boot, grub-efi, zfs

I have two M2 drives. The old one appears to be in pre-fail mode, so I am trying to migrate my system over to the new M2 drive. I have successfully created four partitions (boot, swap, bpool, rpool) on the M2 drive. Here are the layouts of my drives:

```
nvme0n1                                          rpool  /dev/nvme0n1   zfs_member
|-nvme0n1p1 68f4123e-f220-4ea3-8746-339e258a1f75        /dev/nvme0n1p1 vfat
|-nvme0n1p2 e692f860-5c8c-3f4a-816b-66a2d7e79ab5        /dev/nvme0n1p2 swap
|-nvme0n1p3 78355110-6778-1e4e-99d9-a4fc5710b98e bpool  /dev/nvme0n1p3 zfs_member
`-nvme0n1p4 9cc22f93-728b-5f49-91a7-baa51221c316 rpool  /dev/nvme0n1p4 zfs_member
nvme1n1                                                 /dev/nvme1n1   
|-nvme1n1p1 7b0882df-0a4c-4c3a-ac2b-7c82460d7115 EFI    /dev/nvme1n1p1 vfat
|-nvme1n1p2 6919f33c-901a-4f83-bdc7-6ede83ea5a5a        /dev/nvme1n1p2 swap
|-nvme1n1p3 d190dac1-dd2d-4c18-9089-f6c884f227c5 bpool  /dev/nvme1n1p3 zfs_member
`-nvme1n1p4 3399b10d-ecb6-402f-8aa2-2e503e92cb90 rpool  /dev/nvme1n1p4 zfs_member
```

Here is the status of the `rpool`:

```
  pool: rpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: resilvered 254G in 0 days 00:05:32 with 0 errors on Fri Nov 12 11:22:50 2021
config:

    NAME                                      STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    rpool                                     ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0                                ONLINE       0     0     0
        9cc22f93-728b-5f49-91a7-baa51221c316  ONLINE       0     0     0
        3399b10d-ecb6-402f-8aa2-2e503e92cb90  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

The status of the `bpool`

```
  pool: rpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: resilvered 254G in 0 days 00:05:32 with 0 errors on Fri Nov 12 11:22:50 2021
config:

    NAME                                      STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    rpool                                     ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0                                ONLINE       0     0     0
        9cc22f93-728b-5f49-91a7-baa51221c316  ONLINE       0     0     0
        3399b10d-ecb6-402f-8aa2-2e503e92cb90  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

I tried rebooting and selecting the second hard drive (`nvme1`) from the boot menu. However, I get a message saying it's an invalid boot device. How can I boot off of the second drive so I can remove the original drive (`nvme1`) from the pool? I've tried doing the following:

```
sudo mkdosfs -F 32 -s 1 -n EFI /dev/disk/nvme1n1p1
sudo grub-install /dev/nvme1n1p1
```

That does not appear to have worked. Any pointers?